# Customizing Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

I would very much like to customize the Report Viewer of SSRS. I would like to change the looks of the parameters selection/text-boxes and general look-and-feel. Currently my report parameter selection is the default and I would like to provide a more flat look-and-feel. Is it possible? how can I do that?

Comment: One option is you can hide the `default` parameter prompt and design your own using the UI controls.

Comment: @CoderofCode I did though about it... but right now I don't have that much time in hand...